# Define the order of model when use Sequelize.import

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am now using Sequelize, a node.js orm. According to the example, I have the code as below:

module.exports = function(callback) {

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
  var logger = require(path.join(__dirname, '../logger/logger.js'));
  var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../config/settings.json'), 'utf8'));
  var dbConnectionInfo = require(path.join(__dirname, '../../lib/util/dbConnectionInfo.js'))(settings.dbUri);
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConnectionInfo.dbUri,{logging:false});

  sequelize.authenticate()
.then(function() {
  if (callback) {
    callback();
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  logger.error('DB Connection failed ', error);
  if (callback) {
    callback(error);
  }
});
  var db = {};

  fs
.readdirSync(__dirname)
.filter(function(file) {
  return file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== 'index.js';
})
.forEach(function(file) {
  var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
  db[model.name] = model;
});

  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  return db;

}
```

This code will load all the files in "model" folder. 
The problem is that there is a model A that references model B as below shows:

```
var A = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('A', {
    serviceInstanceId: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  field: 'b_id',
  allowNull: false,
  references: {
    model: B,
    key: "b_id",
    deferrable: sequelize.Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE
  }
},

  });
    };
```

But I found that when model A is initializing, it will try to find model B, and model B now is not loaded. So is there a way that can ensure that when it try to load A , B will be load first?

Comment: Have you tried using the table name (as a string) instead of the actual model? See the example under "Enforcing a foreign key reference without constraints" in the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/) for `trainer_id`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can define associations like this when you have Models defined in separate files. You'll have to import all the models first and once all the models were imported you can run an association logic.

There are several ways how to do so but common one and the one i use is to define `associate` classMethod for Models which handle the association.

Model A

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var A = sequelize.define('A', {}, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                A.belongsTo(models.B, {foreignKey: 'b_id'});
            }
        }
    });
    return A;
};
```

Model B

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var B = sequelize.define('B', {}, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                B.hasMany(models.A, {foreignKey: 'b_id'});
            }
        }
    });
    return B;
};
```

Once you have a Model declaration like that and all the models have been imported you can call `associate` function for the models.

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    models[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

This can be placed after the import logic to your index file.

Comment: I updated the code as you shows, but found that the "if ("associate" in db[modelName])" condition is always false, do the associate part will not execute.

Comment: What does the "classMethods" mean? Is it a nodejs keyword or a sequelize keyword? I do not found any material about it.

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/?highlight=classMethods look for classMethods. It's part of definition of sequelize model. Other way is define it directly to model ie B.associate = function(models){...}